# How to Database Query inventory balances from multiple locations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query our inventory database onto an excel spreadsheet in order to find the inventory balances at multiple locations.  The two locations are 'MASTER' which is our main warehouse, and 'ANN-FISH' which is a satellite location.

I need to pull a list of all items located in the satellite location and pull the balances of these items at that location and also the balances of just those items from the MASTER location.

Three tables exist for this data.  'item' table just lists general info about the item. 'inventory' which is where most of the data for this query comes from. And 'invbalances' shows the quantity of an item.

This WHERE statement is sufficient to pull the needed data for the 'ANN-FISH' location:

```
SELECT 
    inventory.itemnum, item.description, inventory.location, inventory.minlevel, inventory.sstock, invbalances.curbal

FROM 
    MX7PROD.dbo.invbalances invbalances, MX7PROD.dbo.inventory inventory, MX7PROD.dbo.item item

WHERE 
    invbalances.itemnum = inventory.itemnum AND 
    invbalances.itemnum = item.itemnum AND 
    invbalances.location = inventory.location AND 
    invbalances.binnum = inventory.binnum AND 
    invbalances.siteid = inventory.siteid AND 
    invbalances.itemsetid = inventory.itemsetid AND 
    invbalances.itemsetid = item.itemsetid AND 
    inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum AND 
    inventory.itemsetid = item.itemsetid AND 
    ((inventory.location='ANN-FISH')) 
ORDER BY inventory.itemnum
```

So, in summary, I would like to somehow also pull the 'curbal' of location 'MASTER' filtered by only the items that exist in location 'ANN-FISH'.

Can someone please help me figure out how to structure the where statement?

Comment: Your question is unclear; it would be helpful if you were to include examples of the data you have, what you're trying to do with it,and what it should look like in the end. See "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]", and this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Comment: It appears like you want to combine two identical tables....   If so, one way to do so it with [sql's `UNION ` Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), thereby avoiding a your unusual/large `WHERE` clause. You shouldn't ever have to list *every* field like this.

Comment: What is *'curbal'*? A field in table? By the way, you should use explicit joins with `JOIN` (a standard since ANSI-92) over implicit join with `WHERE` to join tables. Please also include more of SQL query.

Comment: This is auto generated SQL from MS Query, the internal MS Office tool to pull external data.  What you see here is what MS Query generated through the wizard.  'curbal' is Current Balance, the quantity of an item on hand.

This is how the table columns come out:

itemnum description location minlevel sstock curbal

That is all info related to location 'ANN-FISH'

I just want to add another column to the end to show curbal from location MASTER in addition to this current data.

Comment: Please show table structure and desired output